# Permission settings in my Firebase DB for RESTful API with Angular 2

Tags: rest, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsonp

Are there any special setting need to be done in Firebase DB, so Firebase can send JSON response to Angular HTTP request?

Are there any restrictions in RESTful web services such as this in general?